# JQuery treeview collapse last clicked menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, treeview

I am using Jquery treeview to show my menu list in web page, on Click of an list-item in the treeview opens a new page.in New page how can I make last clicked list-item parent menu as collapsable and remaining all menu list should be in expandable mode.

**Main.html**

```
    
    
    jQuery mtree.js demos
    

    
    
      
        Africa
          
            Algeria
            Marocco
            Libya
            Somalia
            Kenya
            Mauritania
            South Africa
          
        
        America
          
            North-America
              
                Canada
                USA
                  
                    New York
                    California
                      
                        Los Angeles
                        San Diego
                        Sacramento
                        San Francisco
                        Bakersville
                      
                    
                    Lousiana
                    Texas
                    Nevada
                    Montana
                    Virginia
                  
                
              
            
            Middle-America
              
                Mexico
                Honduras
                Guatemala
              
            
            South-America
              
                Brazil
                Argentina
                Uruguay
                Chile
              
            
          
        
        Asia
          
            China
            India
            Malaysia
            Thailand
            Vietnam
            Singapore
            Indonesia
            Mongolia
          
        
        Europe
          
            North
              
                Norway
                Sweden
                Finland
              
            
            East
              
                Romania
                Bulgaria
                Poland
              
            
            South
              
                Italy
                Greece
                Spain
              
            
            West
              
                France
                England
                Portugal
              
            
          
        
        Oceania
          
            Australia
            New Zealand
          
        
        Arctica
        Antarctica
    
     
     
     
     
    THIS IS MAIN PAGE
```

**kenya.html**

```
    
    
    jQuery mtree.js demos
    

    
    
      
        Africa
          
            Algeria
            Marocco
            Libya
            Somalia
            Kenya
            Mauritania
            South Africa
          
        
        America
          
            North-America
              
                Canada
                USA
                  
                    New York
                    California
                      
                        Los Angeles
                        San Diego
                        Sacramento
                        San Francisco
                        Bakersville
                      
                    
                    Lousiana
                    Texas
                    Nevada
                    Montana
                    Virginia
                  
                
              
            
            Middle-America
              
                Mexico
                Honduras
                Guatemala
              
            
            South-America
              
                Brazil
                Argentina
                Uruguay
                Chile
              
            
          
        
        Asia
          
            China
            India
            Malaysia
            Thailand
            Vietnam
            Singapore
            Indonesia
            Mongolia
          
        
        Europe
          
            North
              
                Norway
                Sweden
                Finland
              
            
            East
              
                Romania
                Bulgaria
                Poland
              
            
            South
              
                Italy
                Greece
                Spain
              
            
            West
              
                France
                England
                Portugal
              
            
          
        
        Oceania
          
            Australia
            New Zealand
          
        
        Arctica
        Antarctica
    
     
     
     
     
    THIS IS Kenya PAGE
```

When I click on Africa--> kenya in main.html page it is redirecting to kenya.html i want to highlight Kenya link in kenya.html page.

Comment: could you provide us with some code and may a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to give code in jsfiddle i am new to development. My code will be looks like http://jsbin.com/ebapay/1/edit when i click on level 2-->level 2.1-->a1 it will opens new page a1.html in that page menu list level 2 should be collapsed with a1 red background and other menu list should be in closed mode

Comment: [YOUR SOURCE AT JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwza/9bthLc55/) easy to add.

Comment: Edited your answere. Added a jsfiddle and a snippet :) But actually I still don't really understand what you trying to achieve